# Visual Studio debug jump out of loop

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2005

I know about basic features of visual studio debugging. <kbd>F10</kbd>, <kbd>F11</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>.

If I am inside a for loop is there a way of stopping right after the loop is completed?
Right now the way I am doing it is to manually go to the location after the loop and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>. Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Yes, run to cursor is available, that is the what `ctrl-F10` keyboard that I mention does.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

There is no dedicated "Step Out of Loop" command in Visual Studio. ["Step Out"](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zainnab/archive/2010/10/29/step-out-of-or-over-a-method-vstipdebug0035.aspx) (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>) works only for functions. There are only two options that I can think of:

1. Like Brian suggests, there is [Run to Cursor](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zainnab/archive/2010/05/05/run-to-cursor-vstipdebug0023.aspx), which has been there *at least* since VC++ 6. This is what you're already getting with the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> keyboard shortcut. I use this literally all the time while debugging; it's an extremely useful tool. I don't really understand why you think this is a lousy way of doing it, or why you think there should be a "better" way.
2. You could set a simple [breakpoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k80ex6de.aspx) on the line of code immediately following the loop. This is relatively simple if you use the keyboard shortcut <kbd>F9</kbd>. But you still have to navigate to the appropriate line of code, so you might as well use Run to Cursor.

If you're working in a C-derived language, your loops probably conclude with a `}`. So you could use the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> keyboard shortcut to move to the matching brace in the source file if your caret is at the loop's opening brace. That might make navigation easier. It certainly can help avoid moving your hands over to the mouse, killing precious seconds.

* Note that keyboard combinations are subject to change, depending on how you have configured your Visual Studio environment.

Comment: I use the run to cursor a lot too. But if the loop is fairly big it takes moving the cursor with the mouse to get to the point. It would be nice to have this available but I still quite happy to just use the run to cursor feature.

Answer (score 7):

I just found out that if you hover with your cursor at beginning of the desired line, VS automatically blends in a little play symbol. When you click on it, debugger jumps to this point.
[image: VS debug jumping]

Comment: Thank you !! Perfect !! This saves so much time. Visual Studio 2017 is brilliant...

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you would like to use a [breakpoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k80ex6de%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), which can be used to trigger the debugger once your program has reached a specific line. You can set one by clicking on the left side of the code line, where errors and arrows usually show up during debugging. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Simple way is to put a break statement in the for loop and add a condition. This will allow you to test the loop while debugging.